# Drawing a cosine wave based on mouse position

Tags: javascript, three.js

Intention: The cosine wave should get longer or shorter depending on the x position of the mouse cursor. The point of interest is the mouseMoveHandler function.

```
(function(window,document,undefined){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = rect.right,
    twopi = 2*Math.PI, 

    scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 10;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

/*Point of interest*/
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xf9f9f9}),
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
    line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);


var mouseMoveHandler = function(e){
  var j = 0,
      a = e.clientX/x,
      b = a*(3*twopi);

  for(i=0; i < b; i += .01){
    geometry.vertices[j] = new THREE.Vector3(i, Math.cos(i), 0);
    j = j+1;
    geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  } 

  scene.add(line);
}

var loop = function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

window.onmousemove = mouseMoveHandler;
loop();

})(this,document);
```

What I would expect this code to do is draw the cosine wave then when the mouse is moved, the vertices of the line segments would be updated to reflect the new position. What does happen is the line is generated once when the mouse moves into the screen and then never updates.

I'm unsure how to use verticesNeedUpdate, so my assumption so far is that it deals with that.

In my previous attempts I `.push`ed values into the 'geometry.vertices' array, but that only allowed the wave to lengthen and not shorten when the mouse moves to the left.

Comment: Quick question, why do you have `undefined` passed in as a parameter in `(function(window,document,undefined){`?

Comment: That shouldn't be there, but it's for protective reasons. If this were part of a larger project and someone set undefined to true or something this would not recognize that and in the scope of this particular function undefined would be...well...undefined.

Answer (score 0):

See [ThreeJS Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates#geometries):

> You can only update content of buffers, you cannot resize buffers (this is very costly, basically equivalent to creating new geometry).
>
> You can emulate resizing by pre-allocating a larger buffer and then keeping unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden.

Your vertices are being updated as expected, but the geometry is being limited to the initial size when the vertices were first updated.

You can work around this by pre-allocating a fixed length of vertices.

You could also just create a new geometry/line on each update, but obviously that's very inefficient.

Also look into [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferGeometry), which is the ideal approach for what you're trying to achieve. i.e., pre-allocate a points buffer, then use geometry.setDrawRange() to extend the length of the geometry according to your mouse position.